# K8s ingress socket.io 503

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, socket.io, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have a Nodejs with socket.io app running on EKS with a ELB. I have configured an ingress with the following yaml.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: ws-gateway
    nginx.org/websocket-services: ws-gateway
  name: web-socket
  namespace: default
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: ws-gateway
      port:
        number: 9090
  rules:
  - host: ws.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: ws-gateway
            port:
              number: 9090
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - ws.example.com
    secretName: ws-tls
```

However, when testing this I am receiving `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable`. The domain name and service name and port are correct. The request is not reaching the app either.

Is there something that I am missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was on the service side. The containers were restarting unexpectedly because of connection lost to some other service, which cause a 503 every time I tried to access it.